# What's the point of passing global objects as parameters to a self-executing function?

Tags: javascript

I often see this pattern in Javascript libraries:

```
(function (window, document, $, undefined) {
    window.foo = 'bar';
})(window, document, jQuery);
```

In this example, what's the point of passing `window`, `document`, and `jQuery` since these are global properties and accessible directly, like this:

```js
(function () {
    window.foo = 'bar';
})();

console.log(foo);
```

Is it just a matter of cleanliness, or has it another purpose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One benefit is that it allows the minified version of the library to replace the parameter names. For example:

```
(function (window) {
    window.foo = 'bar';
})(window);
```

Can be minified to

```
(function(w){w.foo='bar'})(window);
```

whereas

```
(function () {
    window.foo = 'bar';
})();
```

can only be minified to

```
(function(){window.foo='bar'})();
```

which isn't much of an improvement. Global objects can't be renamed, but parameter names can.

The usage of `undefined` as a parameter not passed to the function ensures that references to `undefined` inside the function *actually is* `undefined`, and not some other value that a crazy piece of code assigned to a variable named `undefined`, eg:

```js
(() => {
  // absurd code that has a possibility of existing:
  const undefined = 'foo';

  // library code:
  // does not work:
  (() => {
    let someVarName;
    // We expect someVarName to be undefined because someVarName hasn't been assigned to, but:
    console.log(someVarName === undefined);
  })();
})();
```

As a fix, you can use a parameter that definitely isn't passed to the function:

```js
(() => {
  // absurd code that has a possibility of existing:
  const undefined = 'foo';

  // library code:
  // DOES work:
  ((undefined) => {
    let someVarName;
    console.log(someVarName === undefined);
  })();
})();
```

Given that library code usually runs on the top level, this is *mostly* a relic of the past, back when `undefined` was reassignable on the top level, which it luckily isn't in modern browsers.